# The use of the terms 'weaker' and 'stronger' in theorems and assumptions

Tags: proof-writing

This may be a basic question, but I'm not a native English speaker. So I just wanted to obtain clarification on something:

A theorem is weaker resp. stronger if the assumptions/conditions needed to prove the theorem are stronger resp. weaker. Is this correct?

Comment: I think it is as simple as: if  A implies B, but B does not imply A, we say that A is stronger than B.